# Synchronizing a collection of Mercurial repositories

Tags: mercurial, synchronization

I have a collection of Mercurial repositories on a network share. To enable offline work, I want a local copy of this collection on my laptop, and an easy way to synchronize the two when I'm online.

For this, I wrote a quick script that automatically synchronizes each local repository with the corresponding remote repository (push and pull), but it's missing a couple of desirable features:

- automatic cloning of new repositories from the local to the remote collection (and vice versa)
- the ability to organize (move/rename) a local repository and have the change being applied on the remote side as well, the next time I synchronize
- the ability to synchronize `hg strip` and other commands that rewrite repository history
- the ability to synchronize against a `hgwebdir` collection or even Bitbucket

Are there any existing solutions that provide some (or all) of these features?

Comment: Added a tag for synchronization

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge nothing like this exists.  The safest way to move changesets back and forth between repositories is always `hg push` and `hg pull` and none of those command operate on more than one source or destination repository.

For backup purposes I've done something like this before:

```
for thedir in $(find . -type d -name .hg) ; do
   repopath=$(dirname $thedir)
   hg push $repopath ssh://mybackupserver//path/to/backups/$(basename $repopath)
done
```

which pushes all local repos to off site backups.  In theory you could do both push and pull and if necessary a init/clone, but you'll start running into edge ccases pretty quickly.

Comment: Yeah, this is basically what I'm doing now. :-/