# Synchronizing actual version of Mercurial repository for multiple workplaces

Tags: mercurial, repository, push, commit

I have three different Linux-based working places, each with a different computer. I need to have a repository synchronized to keep coding on the latest version each time I move from a workplace to another. You can always commit and push to, say, bitbucket and then pull from another computer, but this is not the purpose of a commit.

Other similar posts did not help, like [Synchronizing a collection of Mercurial repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11378106/synchronizing-a-collection-of-mercurial-repositories).

Any suggestion?

Comment: So, in what way does your question differ from the one you actually linked? What is in your eyes the 'purpose of a commit'? Did you consider commit hooks?

Comment: You typically commit when there's some body of work finished. With my current agenda I could complete a new line of code and head somewhere else...  As for the other question, looks like these repositories do not store the same project, but different ones.

Comment: You can commit "when (you want)|(it's needed)" Separate permanent WIP-branch will be OK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two primary options for exchanging temporary work between repositories are Mercurial Queues and the [evolve extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/EvolveExtension).

Mercurial Queues are documented fairly extensively [here](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/managing-change-with-mercurial-queues.html). To use them for your purpose, you have to put the patches under version control (explained near the bottom of the chapter) and can then push them to/pull them from a shared patch repository. Note that the book is a few years old and Mercurial has added some convenience features in the meantime. These days you can do operations on the patch repository directly via the `--mq` option (e.g., `hg init --mq`, `hg commit --mq`, `hg push --mq`) and don't need a bash alias for convenience.

Evolve is probably more intuitive; it provides a fairly straightforward approach to shared mutable history. You can commit changes in one repository, push the changes to a shared repository, pull from another and uncommit or alter them, then push them back.

In order to set this up, you need a shared repository somewhere that is declared as [non-publishing](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Phases#Publishing_Repository). You do this by adding the following lines to its `.hg/hgrc`:

```
[phases]
publish = False
```

This prevents changesets exchanged through this repository from becoming public (at which point, they'd become immutable).

You will also need to install the extension first (unlike MQ, which is part of core Mercurial).

Note that Bitbucket currently does not support obsolescence markers, which are crucial for the functioning of changeset evolution, so you will need to host the shared repository in a different place. Evolve functions not by deleting outdated changesets, but by marking them as obsolete and hiding them (obsolescence markers also track how old and new changesets are related). Because Bitbucket does not support these markers, obsolete changesets will become visible again if pushed there. (Note that you can still use evolve locally or between evolve-aware repositories and use Bitbucket for public stuff.)

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different ways:

1. Handwork

   - MQ with [MQCollab extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MqCollabExtension)
   - Commits with "classic" exchange between repos using [MuliRepo extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MultirepoExtension) (just don't forget `hg pull` on every workplace before pull - and add all remote repos into `[multirepo]` section on each workplace)
2. Automated way

   - Create additional "central hub" and use [AutoSync extension](https://bitbucket.org/obensonne/hg-autosync/wiki/Home)

Comment: Love the automated way, of course. Can a bitbucket repository be programmed to behave like that central hub?

Comment: @nightcod3r - because I can't see requirement "run *anything*" on central repo, yes, I *think* it's possible